# Javascript array to PHP with json.stringify

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have an array of divs is js:

```
[div#heaolu, div#edu, div#usk, div#lootus, div#heaenergia]
```

I need to pass that to PHP.

JS:

```
function send(){
            console.log(sendarray);

            JSON.stringify(sendarray);
}
```

PHP:

```
$posts = json_decode($_POST['sendarray']);


print_r($posts); 
echo json_last_error();
```

print_r return nothing and json_last_error returns 0 in firefox

In chrome it throws me: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: please first check your sendarray is working or not

Comment: console.log(sendarray) returns [div#heaolu, div#edu, div#usk, div#lootus, div#heaenergia], so it works

Comment: How are you sending the data from the client to the server?  Are you using something like the JQuery AJAX functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is not a valid javascript object, you have to wrap the elements in `"`. Also, look at @Rahul Desai's answer, you need to send the data to the server using ajax.

```
["div#heaolu", "div#edu", "div#usk", "div#lootus", "div#heaenergia"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AJAX to pass data from Javascript to PHP.

[AJAX | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

[Javascript AJAX PHP tutorials | Google](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=Javascript+AJAX+PHP+tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

In order to send the data to the server you could use [JQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post).